# Installing wro4j plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I'm looking to install the [wro4j](/questions/tagged/wro4j) plugin for [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse).  Can someone show me how to to install this or point me to a page that can show me how to install it.

The specific version of eclipse is
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149

This plugin created / supported by JBoss and is located here.

https://github.com/jbosstools/m2e-wro4j

I'm just unfamiliar w/the installation process.  I typically use the Help/Install New Software in eclipse however this doesn't look like an option for this plugin.

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **Install new software** window, you'll need to add the wro4j update site in the **Work with** field. According to the page you linked to above, the wro4j release site is http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2e-wro4j/

After you add that update site, you should be able to see the wro4j features/plugins that are available. Note that depending on how the update site is structured, you might have to un-check the option **Group items by category**.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, please click the Accept button/link so that credit is assigned.